# Strange batch file behaviour on subfunctions

Tags: batch-file

The below code I expect to print out two lines on the command window. Why is it printing 3 lines?

```
@echo off


call:myDosFunc1 100 YeePEE
goto:yyy


:myDosFunc1    - here starts my function identified by it`s label
echo. it could do %~1 of things %~2.
:yyy



call:myDosFunc2 100 YeePEE
goto:ttt


:myDosFunc2   - here starts my function identified by it`s label
echo. it could do %~1 of things %~2.

:ttt
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `@echo off` line and add the `pause` command at the end and you can watch the flow that the script takes.  The reason behind your issues is that you are not returning from `:myDosFunc1`, so the code is falling through to `myDosFunc2`, meaning `:myDicFunc2` is getting called twice.

Simple fix, Add the following to your `myDosFunc1`

```
:myDosFunc1    - here starts my function identified by it`s label
echo. it could do %~1 of things %~2.
goto:eof
:yyy
```

#### Recommendation: Structure your script like so to prevent workflow issues.

```
@echo off

call:myDosFunc1 100 YeePEE
call:myDosFunc2 100 YeePEE
exit /b 0

:myDosFunc1    - here starts my function identified by it`s label
echo. it could do %~1 of things %~2.
exit /b 0

:myDosFunc2   - here starts my function identified by it`s label
echo. it could do %~1 of things %~2.
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that unlike `C` or `Delphi` or other languages where a procedure-names are explicit and reaching the end of a procedure implies a return, batch acts like assembler, where labels are simply markers. Reaching a label does nothing - batch charges on through regardless. Reaching end-of-file (or using the inbuilt `GOTO :EOF` implicitly returns or terminates if the return stack is exhausted. `EXIT /b` is an explicit return which can also optionally set `errorlevel`.